# maya to fbx with custom attributes

Tags: python, maya, fbx

I have a maya scene where each mesh has a list of custom attributes on the shape node that I add dynamically using python.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mm

#get mesh objects.
meshes = maya.cmds.ls(type="mesh")
for mesh in meshes:
    cmds.select(mesh)   


    #check if attribute exists, if not, create.
    if not mm.eval( 'attributeExists "test" "%s"' % mesh): 
        cmds.addAttr( shortName='tst', longName='test', dataType="string")
```

When I export to .fbx and re-import, these attributes and their values are gone.

How can I keep all these values upon export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.  From the [maya docs](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-AA3B8EA4-DDFB-4B0F-9654-2BF6B8781AE7-htm.html):

> You can export Maya transform node custom attributes to the user properties of FbxNode. However, you cannot export Maya shape node custom attributes, such as mesh node, to FbxGeometry. This is because FbxGeometry does not currently support user properties.

Your best bet is probably to try putting the custom attributes on a non-shape node if possible, or else exploring other export formats like [alembic](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Alembic-Export-htm.html) or your own custom format.

Comment: Also, FBX will truncate long attribute names - i'm not sure what the character limit is but above a certain length the become garbled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to get the same result on a transform node, or a locator, but this:

 loc = cmds.spaceLocator( p=(0,0,0) )  
    
    if not mm.eval( 'attributeExists "shader" "%s"' % loc): 
        cmds.addAttr( shortName='shd', longName='shader', dataType="string")

cmds.setAttr( loc + '.shader', 'this', type="string" )


gives an error:

can only concatenate list (not "str") to list #

Comment: the string to list error is because spaceLocator returns both the transform and the shape: you need to get only the first component of `loc`